# 一会 vs 一下 vs 一时 vs 一时半会 vs 片刻

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I wanted to say "I'm going to take a nap for a while" and looked for the phrase "(for) a while" in Chinese and came across these 5 :
一会，一下，一时，一时半会，片刻。

Could you please tell me the difference between those five?

Will there be any difference if I say :

> 我要去小睡一会
>
> 我要去小睡一下
>
> 我要去小睡一时
>
> 我要去小睡一时半会
>
> 我要去小睡片刻

???

And last, does adding "儿" to 一会/一下 change the meaning?

Thank you in advance!!!

(Ps : I'm a beginner in Chinese. I'm sorry if my question sounds silly or something. Also, it'd be very helpful if you could provide some examples while explaining things so I can understand better).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would say

> 我要去小睡片刻 or 我要去小睡一会儿

Other expressions you have are not normally used.

You could also say

> 我要稍微睡一会儿

---

All the phrases you have can refer to a short interval of time in certain context, but they can have different meanings, 一下

> 一下，a short interval of time, for example, 灯一下又亮了
>
> 一下，once, for example, 你过去打他一下
>
> 一下，sudden, for example, 天一下就黑了

一时 has the following meanings

> 一时，a short interval of time, for example, 你别一时想不开
>
> 一时，a period of time, for example, 此一时彼一时
>
> 一时，at the same time, for example, 一时间，箭、弩都发射出去

And the others

> 一会，a short interval of time, for example, 我要出去一会
>
> 一时半会（儿），a short interval of time, for example, 他们一时半会儿还回不来
>
> 片刻，a short interval of time, for example, 请稍等片刻

I am only listing the common meanings and although they could have same meaning, the way you use them could be different and that is why I included the examples.

---

Adding 儿 after 一会 would not change its meaning, it just sounds more natural and is highly recommended. However, there is no such use of adding 儿 after 一下。

Answer (score 1):

No difference, It is about what sayings are more popular than the others. it could depend on where you came from(different education level and/or region).

Comment: You are welcome! :)